# NGINX UDP upstream health

Tags: nginx, udp, load-balancing

We are using the open source vesion of NGINX to load balance UDP. According to the documentation:

> *Passive Health Monitoring*
>
> *If an attempt to connect to an upstream server times out or results in an error, NGINX Open Source or NGINX Plus can mark the server as
>   unavailable and stop sending requests to it for a defined amount of
>   time. To define the conditions under which NGINX considers an upstream
>   server unavailable, include the following parameters to the server
>   directive*
>
> ***fail_timeout*** – The amount of time within which a specified number of connection attempts must fail for the server to be considered
>   unavailable. Also, the amount of time that NGINX considers the server
>   unavailable after marking it so.
>
> ***max_fails*** – The number of failed attempts that happen during the specified time for NGINX to consider the server unavailable.

How are these handled in a UDP scenario where there are no connections?